# Haskell Dynamic/TypeRep: extract instance of a typeclass without knowing the full type?

Tags: haskell, dynamic, casting

If I have a `TypeRep` for a type or a `Dynamic` containing an instance of that type, is there any way I can find the appropriate instance of a known typeclass to enable me to call a function on that typeclass without needing to know the full type in question?  If there isn't such a feature, is there a reason it would be impossible, or has it just not been implemented?

Alternatively, is there a way (perhaps using template haskell) to run through a generated list of all types with instances of a typeclass so that I can perform a dynamic cast on each and check the results?

What I'm trying to do is implement `Eq` and a version of `Show` that actually displays the data for `Dynamic` (whenever possible) for the purposes of writing simpler and more generally useful unit tests; I don't really need high performance for this so using generated code that runs through all the possibilities would be acceptable.

Comment: I'm curious as to your use-case here. Why are you working with `Dynamic` in the first place?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm working on an interpreter for an object-oriented language, and want to allow embedding of arbitrary Haskell values into its own value type to allow object methods implemented as Haskell code to store whatever values they need in the objects of the target language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to check if a type is an instance of something at runtime. One of the reasons is that importing a module could bring in new instances and that would change the result of the function (this would be very bad for Haskell).

You can go though a list of known types. The idea is you store the type along with the instances for that type in a `GADT` and match on it to get the instances you want. I'm not exactly sure what you want but I think it's something like this:

```
data EqShow where
  JustEq :: (Typeable a, Eq a)         => Proxy a -> EqShow
  EqShow :: (Typeable a, Eq a, Show a) => Proxy a -> EqShow
```

There's a version for types that only have `Eq` and one that have both `Eq` and `Show`. The idea is we can match on these if the types match and use the `Eq` instance to check if they're equal. If a `Show` instance is available we can show the results too. To store multiple EqShows I've used a hash map so we can lookup the types. Here's the full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import           Data.Dynamic
import           Data.Typeable
import           Data.HashMap.Lazy (HashMap)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HM

data EqShow where
  JustEq :: (Typeable a, Eq a)         => Proxy a -> EqShow
  EqShow :: (Typeable a, Eq a, Show a) => Proxy a -> EqShow

justEq :: (Typeable a, Eq a) => Proxy a -> (TypeRep, EqShow)
justEq p = (typeRep p, JustEq p)

eqShow :: (Typeable a, Eq a, Show a) => Proxy a -> (TypeRep, EqShow)
eqShow p = (typeRep p, EqShow p)

-- | Different outcomes of testing equality.
data Result
  = DifferentType TypeRep TypeRep
  | NotEq TypeRep (Maybe (String, String))
  | IsEq TypeRep (Maybe String)
  | UnknownType TypeRep
  deriving Show

-- | Check if two Dynamics are equal. Show them if possible
dynEq :: HashMap TypeRep EqShow -> Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Result
dynEq hm da db
  | ta /= tb  = DifferentType ta tb
  | otherwise =
      case HM.lookup ta hm of
        Just (EqShow p) -> checkEqShow p (fromDynamic da) (fromDynamic db)
        Just (JustEq p) -> checkJustEq p (fromDynamic da) (fromDynamic db)
        Nothing         -> UnknownType ta
  where
    ta = dynTypeRep da
    tb = dynTypeRep db

    -- Check if two results are equal and display them.
    checkEqShow :: (Typeable a, Eq a, Show a) => Proxy a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Result
    checkEqShow _ (Just a) (Just b)
      | a == b    = IsEq ta (Just (show a))
      | otherwise = NotEq ta (Just (show a, show b))
    checkEqShow _ _ _ = UnknownType ta

    -- Check if two results are equal without displaying them.
    checkJustEq :: (Typeable a, Eq a) => Proxy a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Result
    checkJustEq p (Just a) (Just b)
      | a == b    = IsEq ta Nothing
      | otherwise = NotEq ta Nothing
    checkJustEq p _ _ = UnknownType ta
```

You can them make a list of known types:

```
knownEqShows :: HashMap TypeRep EqShow
knownEqShows = HM.fromList
  [ eqShow (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
  , eqShow (Proxy :: Proxy Char)
  ]
```

and check them:

```
> let a = toDyn 'a'
> let b = toDyn 'b'
> let c = toDyn (1 :: Int)
> dynEq knownEqShows a a
IsEq Char (Just "'a'")
> dynEq knownEqShows a b
NotEq Char (Just ("'a'","'b'"))
> dynEq knownEqShows a c
DifferentType Char Int
```

Generating known `EqShow`s using template haskell would be difficult. You might be able to make a version for types without variables (`Double`, `Char` etc.) But if you have a variable (`Maybe a` for instance) you wouldn't be able to store this in EqShow, you'd have to write all versions of it (`Maybe Int`, `Maybe (Maybe Double)` etc.) but there's an infinite number of these.

---

Of course it would be much easier instead of using `Dynamic` to use another wrapper (is possible):

```
data EqShowDynamic where
  JustEqD :: (Typeable a, Eq a)         => a -> EqShowDynamic
  EqShowD :: (Typeable a, Eq a, Show a) => a -> EqShowDynamic
```

So the `Eq` and `Show` instances are already there.

Comment: Looking over the cases I'm going to need to use this, I think your easier approach of using a wrapper is probably the best way, but thanks for all the ideas. :)

Comment: I actually decided in the end to go a rather different route.  The result is now [up on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-dynamic).